# How to change the " on my site

Tags: quotation-marks

I installed a new theme in my blog. I noticed that the theme is showing quotation marks " " as “ ”. Please help me to sort out this problem. I don't want these quotation marks as “ ”, I want them simple " ". Please help.

Comment: It would help if you can identify the specific theme and blogging engine being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely it's the font of the theme thats desides how the " are beeing displayed..

You can change the font-family if you go into the stylesheet (css file).

Comment: Ok, would you care to explain?

Comment: We don't know anything about the system he is using. I could speculate that he is using Wordpress, and would like to [disable Wordpress' smart quotes](http://www.lancebledsoe.com/how-to-turn-off-wordpress-smart-quotes).

Comment: Thank you so much JezenThomas & f01 for your responses.
Yes, I use WordPress and I used the steps explained in the article at lancebledsoe and sorted out the problem.
Thanks again!